# iOS, Unable to delegate outside of viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, object, viewdidload

I have this appdelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface appDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
  UIWindow *window;
  NSString *name;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@end
```

and the .m file

```
@synthesize name;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    name=@"john";
    return YES;
   }
```

Now...I want to get this name from another controller, if I try to call it inside my viewDidLoad methods, it works..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    appDelegate *test= (appDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"%@", test.name);
}
```

but If I try to do the same thing in my initWithNibName it just didn't work...

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        appDelegate *test= (appDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSLog(@"%@", test.name);
    }
```

Anyone can help me out? This problem is driving me crazy...

Comment: From where you are calling `initWithNibName` i.e. initialising your view controller? have you debugged whether controller come there or not?

Comment: "didn't work" = the name doesn't get printed out

Comment: As @rishi mentioned please confirm whether u r calling initWithNibname method ? put breakpoint and debug whether it comes in execution ?

Comment: Yes the code did go there, I added this line `NSLog(@"test");` just to check and it did get printed out

Comment: What does the declaration of the `appDelegate` object in the .h look like?

Comment: is the viewcontroller the main one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are overriding the `-initWithNibName:`, you need to return an instance of the class (or `self`);
 Try the following code in `-initWithNibName:`. It is working for me.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    appDelegate *test= (appDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSLog(@"%@", test.name);

   if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {

   }
   return self;
}
```

I think this may useful to you.